# How to close entire remaining position on 2nd TP?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to set 2 TPs, however I always have a bit of leftover that needs a third close to clean up.

Here is my current code:

```
acct_size = input(500, group="Trading Settings")
pct_of_account_to_order = input(100, group="Trading Settings") / 100

qty = acct_size * pct_of_account_to_order / close

nbr_tps = input(3, group="Trading Settings")

qty_tp = qty / nbr_tps

qty_tp_pct = 0
```

Now here's my attempt...

```
if strategy.position_size<strategy.position_size[1] and strategy.position_size>0
    qty_tp_pct := 100

if closeLongCond
    strategy.close("Long 1",qty=qty_tp,qty_percent=qty_tp_pct,alert_message=close_long_alert_msg)
```

I'm still getting a "remainder" hanging there that needs to be closed separately, no matter what I try, e.g.:

[image]

I [have read that qty_percent trumps qty in priority](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose) (in pine versin 4 at least), so I figured setting it to 100 would work, but no dice. Could really use some help.

Comment: Actually 'qty_percent' priority is lower than that of the 'qty' parameter. (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}close)

Comment: Hi @StarrLucky and thanks. Looks like that changed in v5. However my script is using v4 (guess I should have stated that, will update my question).

Comment: It is same for v4, just mistake in reference manual